# How to get class_id for every image?

Tags: python, object-detection, pycocotools

How can i dump in the file `class_id` of the image, if i'm using mmdetection.
Should i change in class `aips/test.py` or `datasets/coco.py` or the `config` file for the model ?
as what i'm got this array for every image

```
[3.41282135e+02, 2.03359509e+01, 4.95520966e+02, 3.14121826e+02,
        8.74738395e-01]
```

and i need the structure of the file contains

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,class_id,bbox_score
```